# Android React-Native, how to update index.android.bundle file at runtime?

Tags: android, reactjs, bundle, react-native, android-assets

I am building an android application which has combined functionalities of Native(Android-Kotlin) and React-Native.

We have a requirement to update index.android.bundle file at runtime after the user installed an application. How can I achieve this requirement?

I am having the following queries on the same.

1. Can I place index.android.bundle file outside of assets folder in android?
2. Where can I place Fonts and Drawable assets which are used by react-native functionality?

Requirement is:
After the user installing an application. If we have any updates in react-native functionality without re-publishing an application in play-store, we have to download and update the index.android.bundle file in the assets folder.

As per Android restrictions, we cannot add or change any file in assets folder at run-time/dynamically.